# Continue to perform song independent of the scene

Tags: scripting, game-engine, logic-bricks

I need the music in the main menu of the game to continue running regardless of the scene in which the game is played.

For example: When I am in the main menu the game plays a song when I click on the settings the music stops because of Logic Bricks.

I want the song to continue playing in all scenes except when the game starts.

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Show an image of your logic editor.

Comment: As i can see the ``sound actuator`` play mode is set to ``play stop`` change it to ``play loop``, if that not help change the ``always sensor`` to ``true level triggering`` (the first button with 3 dots).

Comment: No solved... Help me?